# Laravel 5 accessing data with compact

Tags: php, json, laravel

---

Hi everybody,

I hope my post will make sense and you won't think I am total newbie (which I am sometimes..)

I am trying to understand what's the best way to send data to a view in laravel 5 and access these data.

I actually can do it but it feels to me that's a wrong way to do it.

Here is my controller:

```
public function timeline()
{
    $array_articles = array();

    $sharedcontents = DB::table('follow')->select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(sharedcontent_id) as concat_article_id'))
                    ->join('sharedcontent_user', 'sharedcontent_user.user_id', '=', 'follow.user_id')
                    ->where('follower_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->groupBy('sharedcontent_user.sharedcontent_id')
                    ->get();

    foreach ($sharedcontents as $sharedcontent) {

        $article_ids = $sharedcontent->concat_article_id;

        $shareNumber = DB::table('sharedcontent_user')->where('sharedcontent_id', $article_ids)->count();
        $row['share_number']    = $shareNumber;

        $articles = DB::table('shared_content')
                    ->select(   'sharedcontent_user.sharedcontent_id as sharedId',
                                'shared_content.id as articleId',
                                'shared_content.title as articleTitle',
                                'shared_content.source as articleSource',
                                'shared_content.image as articleImage'
                            )
                    ->join('sharedcontent_user', 'sharedcontent_user.sharedcontent_id', '=', 'shared_content.id')
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'sharedcontent_user.user_id')
                    ->get();

        foreach ($articles as $article){

            $shared_content_id  = $article->articleId;

            $row['title']                   = $article->articleTitle;
            $row['source']                  = $article->articleSource;
            $row['image']                   = $article->articleImage;
        }

        array_push($array_articles, $row);
    }
    $articles = json_encode($array_articles);

    return view('timeline', compact('articles'));
}
```

As you can see at the beginning I create an array called: $array_articles
and I then push my row into it.

Before sending it to my view I encode it with JSON and in my view I perform a JSON decode.

My view:

```
<div id="timeline-container" class="container">
<?php $articles = json_decode($articles); ?>
@foreach ($articles as $article)
<div id="article-shared-box">
    <div class="article-shared-box-left pull-left">
        <div class="blend-layer">
            <div class="article-shared-picture"><img src="{{ url($article->image) }}" /></div>
            <div class="category-square">{{ $article->category }}</div>
            <div class="article-shared-title">{{ $article->title }}</div>
            <div class="article-shared-source">{{ $article->source }}</div>
        </div>
...
```

If I don't perform this JSON encode and decode I cannot access my data.

So am I doing it right ?

@update

If I don't encode and decode with JSON I always get the: try to access the property of a non object, no matter how I pass it to the view and no matter how I call my array.

Here is a print_r of my $article_array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [share_number] => 1 [category] => Startup [sharing_user_id0] => 68 [sharing_user_name0] => 건우 박 [sharing_user_picture0] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/723882664388388/picture?type=normal [comment_number] => 1 [most_recent_comment] => hhhh [comment_author] => 건우 박 [title] => 전북도 내 스타트업 육성 … 300억 규모 창조경제 혁신펀드 본격 운용 [source] => Platum [image] => http://platum.kr/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/11941_800799769932697_1056826482061661861_n.jpg ) [1] => Array ( [share_number] => 1 [category] => Startup [sharing_user_id0] => 68
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to encode and decode as this just wastes time. You can give PHP variables to your view, there's no need for any encoding:

```
return view('timeline', array('articles' => (object) $array_articles));
```

Comment: If I do like this it says: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That's because the view is accessing like an object, you can either change the view to reference the variables in an array (eg. `$article['title']`) or you can typecast the array to an object like I have my updated my answer to show.

Comment: It still says im trying to access property of  non object. (I tried both of your solutions) I updated my question with the result of a print_r

Comment: It is simple if you store your data as array you must access it as array - if you want to access it in object notation it must be an object. Don't store your object data `$article->articleTitle;` as an array `$row['title'] = $article->articleTitle;`

Comment: but even if I try to access my data as an array, it doesn't work.. unless I encode / decode with JSON